# Deleted Tomcat without executing shutdown.sh

Tags: tomcat, process, tomcat5.5

I deleted my Tomcat 5.5.30 by mistake without shutting it down. Now even if no tomcat is running sometimes localhost:8080 shows tomcat default page but if I refresh it goes off. Now even I am running a different Tomcat 5.5.30 (with a different port number - 8090) it is not running on that port. I can't find any Tomcat process by using the command **ps -ef | grep Tomcat**. Even restarting the system doesn't help. How to kill this invisible process. I am using Mac Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Use `netstat -plan | grep :8080` (or slightly different options, i don't know Mac OS) to find out which process holds the port.

Oh, and Tomcat processes are probably not called `tomcat`, but rather `java ... Bootstrap ...`. So you should try `jps -v`.

Comment: -plan option doesn't work. I tried using netstat | grep 8080 but doesn't show anything.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, lsof -itcp:8080 prints firefox-b 26529 325366    8u  IPv4 0x0741e688      0t0  TCP 10.0.1.107 .what after that? can u pls guide..

Comment: that's firefox-bin connecting to port 8080. no help there. seems to me I remember something about OSX not showing daemon processes by default? might be an avenue worth pursuing until someone with some Mac knowledge pitches in here.